# Explode function returning single row in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, textarea, explode

Hi actually when i execute the code i get an output it will be spitted in echo statement but if i put echo in textarea i get only last value of string from my database

```
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT naveen from kumar where id<5");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $myString = $row['admin'];
        $myArray  = explode(',', $myString);
        foreach ($myArray as $my_Array) {
            echo $my_Array.'<br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
 <textarea name="valid" cols="60" rows="5"><?php echo $my_Array;?></textarea>
  </form>
    <?php ?>
```

This is my result

[image]

Comment: It does exactly what you told it to do, it prints the value of `$my_Array`, which ist the last value of the array `$myArray`. If you want to have all of the values inside the `<textarea>`, you have to a) concatenate the values via `.=` insode the loop or b) place the loop inside the `<textarea>` tags.

Comment: @imnaveen in text area what you want please let me know?

Comment: @PrabhuNandanKumar in my database admin field i have  two string values its like "test","qwerty" so these two values are need to separate with textarea. so i need to seperate fields where comma in this string

Comment: @imnaveen can show expected output what you want . I mean in same textarea you want to show comma seperated string or two textarea  required, whatever please give example.

Comment: @imnaveen try my answer below. Hope it will help to append data and break line in text area

Answer (score 1):

You should paint a `<textarea>` inside of first bucle (`while`).

```
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT naveen from kumar where id<5");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $myString = $row['admin'];
        $myArray  = explode(',', $myString);
        echo '<textarea name="valid" cols="60" rows="5">';
        foreach ($myArray as $my_Array) {
            echo = $my_Array.'<br>';
        }
        echo '</textarea>';
    }
    ?>
  </form>
```

Comment: it will be working but i have faced again one problem.in this code break statement not working actually i get in result in single row.  "test"<br>"qwerty"<br> but i need one by one in text area..

Comment: ok, i am edit my answer.In this moment I can not prove my code, but this is the idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate your result with previous one. Delcare `$my_Array = "";` before `while` loop For break line in textarea you have to use `&#10;`

```
foreach ($myArray as $my_Array) {
$my_Array .= '&#10;';
echo $my_Array; //IF you also want to echo here
}
```

Comment: and this will add `'<br>'`s to the array and not the values. Should be  `$my_Array .= $myArray.'<br>'`

Comment: No @blewherself `my_Array` is value while `$myArray` is an array you cant concatenate array in value

Comment: these naming of variables is so confusing

Comment: @imnaveen If answer is helpfull then vote up on answer and accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example will solve your issue. Please let me know if you still have any queries.

```
<?php
$myvalue = array('one','two','three');
$myterm =  implode('-', $myvalue);
$mynewvalue = explode('-',$myterm);

?>
<form method="post" action="">
 <textarea name="valid" cols="60" rows="5">
    <?php 
        foreach($mynewvalue as $mvn)
            {
                echo $mvn.',';
            }
    ?>
 </textarea>
 </form>
```

Comment: This code will be work fine but i need the array values are display into separate its any possible in this code the echo values are display into one by one

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display array values separately inside text area like <textarea> a b c</textarea> or like <textarea> a </textarea> <textarea> b </textarea> <textarea> c</textarea>.Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
<?php $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT naveen from kumar where id<5");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
            $myString = $row['admin'];
            $myArray[]  = explode(',', $myString);

        }
        ?>
     <textarea name="valid" cols="60" rows="5"><?php echo implode(" ",$my_Array);?></textarea>
      </form>
        <?php ?>
```